# Get href property for each row in a table using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract all links for a table that looks similar to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://www.r-project.org/">R</a><br>
      <a href="https://www.rstudio.com/">RStudio</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="https://community.rstudio.com/">Rstudio Community</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

What I would like to do is to get a list of dataframes (or vector) at the end where each dataframe contain all the links for each row in the html table. For example, in this case the list will have vector 1 with `c("https://www.r-project.org/","https://www.rstudio.com/")` and the second vector will be `c("https://community.rstudio.com/")`. The main problem I am having right now is that I am not able to keep the href relationship to each node when I do the following:

```
library(rvest)

web <- read_html("table.html") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_nodes("tr") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Here is the output as a list: `rows<-html_nodes(page, "table") %>% html_nodes( "tr")`
`lapply( rows, function(x){x %>% html_nodes( "a") %>% html_attr("href")})`

Comment: @Dave2e , thank you this is a neat solution (I am having a similar issue). Is there a way to have an empty (`NA`) entry for rows without links? This would preserve the number of rows from the original table.

Comment: @Doon_Bogan, To return a NA for empty rows use `html_node("a")` in the lapply statement.  html_node always returns 1 node or NA, html_nodes will return the number of nodes found.  See help for more information.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to add in a search replacing the `"a"` term with `html_node`, which will generate a list of just the first url in each `tr`.  You could then use this to split the full list into groups.

```
page <- read_html("table.html") #just read the html once

web <- page %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% html_nodes("tr") %>% html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") #as above

web2 <- page %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% html_nodes("tr") %>% html_node("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") #just the first url in each tr

webdf <- data.frame(web=web, #full list
                    group=cumsum(web %in% web2), #grouping indicator by tr
                    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

webdf
                             web group
1     https://www.r-project.org/     1
2       https://www.rstudio.com/     1
3 https://community.rstudio.com/     2
```